# Detect navigation abort/cancel in a guard

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

Currently it's expected that the navigation is confirmed, so both `beforeEach` and `afterEach` global guards are triggered. `showSpinner` and `hideSpinner` are supposed to be called in pair on each navigation.

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  showSpinner();
  next();
}

router.afterEach((to, from) => {
  // This line can be never called
  hideSpinner();
});
```

From what I see, navigation result isn't available through `next` in guards.

Then in another place the navigation is cancelled, so it stays on the previous route, and `afterEach` is not triggered (the same likely applies to navigation abort):

```
beforeRouteEnter() {
  ...
  next(false);
}
```

The result is that `afterEach` and `hideSpinner` not being triggered.

This happens with Vue Router 3.4.9 and Vue 2.6.

How can this be solved?

Comment: If I read you correctly, you might be missing something on asynchronously triggered showSpinner & hideSpinner 
So, 
`hideSpinner().then(() => next())`

Comment: @power-cut hideSpinner is not asynchronous, it just changes reactive flag variable. As it was said, the problem is that afterEach may not be called at all.

Comment: check this - `You can also register global after hooks, however unlike guards, these hooks do not get a next function and cannot affect the navigation:`
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-after-hooks

Comment: @power-cut It's a good point, I didn't have `next()` in original code. Any way, it would cause an error, the problem is that afterEach is not called at all. Also I'm using router v3 here, not the latest version that can behave differently.

Comment: I just recreated a minimal workable code.. please have a look. It's working for me as per your mentioned router & vue versions
https://codesandbox.io/embed/fervent-jones-trbzle?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: @power-cut Thanks for the help. The problem is exactly what I described in the question. When a navigation is interrupted, e.g. with next(false), afterEach won't hit, https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-mccarthy-w3071f

Comment: Old post, check this - https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/1048

Answer (score 2):

It seems that there is no built-in way to get an abort event from a canceled  navigation.

However, digging into `vue-router`'s code I found that every transition to a route is handled in `router.history` by `transitionTo` function that accepts as a third argument an abort function, which is called whenever the navigation has not been confirmed. It is possible to intercept that event by overwriting this function.

I'm sure this code will get some critique, but it is here maybe to rise some ideas.

```
const transitionTo = Object.getPrototypeOf(router.history).transitionTo;

Object.getPrototypeOf(router.history).transitionTo = function (...args) {
  const abortFn = args[2] && new Function("return " + args[2].toString());
  args[2] = (err) => {
    // eventBus.$emit("hide-spinner"); // or any other method to hide the spinner
    console.log("Aborted", err);
    abortFn && abortFn(err);
  };
  transitionTo.apply(router.history, args);
};
```

And here is a working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-villani-rik7yn?file=/src/router/index.js)

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure if the use of eval is justified here. I guess abortFn could be just a wrapper function

Answer (score 2):

As I understood from your question, you want **afterEach** is triggered even when the navigation is cancelled. For better answering the question we suppose that we have an **About** route that in some conditions the navigation to this route is cancelled. As [Vue-router documentation](https://v3.router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards) says:

> you can access the instance by passing a callback to next. The callback will be called when the navigation is confirmed, and the component instance will be passed to the callback as the argument.

So in the **About** route we can have this code:

```js
beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
    next(vm => {
      // put your codes here, for example the condition that must be applied
      let condition = true;
      if (condition) {
        vm.$router.push(from.path);
      }
    })
  }
```

By using that code instead of `next(false)`, we actually cancels the navigation to **About** route, but in this case the `afterEach` is also triggered.

Comment: Thanks, the workaround may be usable in some cases, but generally it's a serious change that cancelled router view still needs to be rendered, it could be cancelled for a reason